# Convert time to am/pm flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

How to convert the time to am/pm ?

I have this output

```
I/flutter (17720): 9:00:00
I/flutter (17720): 11:00:00
I/flutter (17720): 12:00:00
```

This is what I have tried

```
 final item = snapshot.data[index];
 print("Time " + item['time'].toString());

 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(item['time'].toString());
 print(DateUtil().formattedTime(dateTime));
```

**DateUtil**

```
 String formattedTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    return DateFormat().add_jm().format(dateTime);
  }
```

**Error**

> I/flutter (17720): Time 09:00:00
>
> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
>   ═══════════════════════════════════ The following FormatException was
>   thrown building Tags(dirty, state: TagsState#b3a2f): Invalid date
>   format 09:00:00

Comment: To be able to format your dates, Dart should know the format you're trying to parse. Check the intl package: https://pub.dev/packages/intl and https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: @Arno seems like I need to have date too

Comment: And, in any case (omitting locale differences), 'converting' to AM/PM is just :if(x > 12) x -12, I guess

Comment: @Arno can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the **intl** library https://pub.dev/packages/intl
and format your DateTime

```
 DateFormat.yMEd().add_jms().format(DateTime.now());
```

Output:

```
'Thu, 5/23/2013 10:21:47 AM'
```

Comment: In that case ````DateFormat.jm().format(DateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse("22:30:00"))````

Answer (score 78):

Use this code:

```
DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(DateTime.now());
```

According to the **intl** library, it states that a represents AM/PM.

Answer (score 12):

[DateFormat class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

DateFormat is for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner.

**Convert Time**

```
print(DateFormat.jm().format(DateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse("14:15:00")));
```

> **Output :** 3:20 AM

**Convert Date**

```
print(DateFormat('yyyy-MMMM-dd').format("2021-05-14 00:00:00.000"));
```

> **Output :** 2021-May-14

### **EXAMPLE :**

**Time Picker**

```
Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: _con.selectedTime,
);
if (picked != null) {
  String selTime =
      picked.hour.toString() + ':' + picked.minute.toString() + ':00';
  print(DateFormat.jm().format(DateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse(selTime)));
}}
```

**Date Picker**

```
_selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: _con.selectDateAndTime,
  firstDate: DateTime(2021),
  lastDate: DateTime(2040),
);
if (picked != null) {
  print(picked);
}}
```

Comment: if i want to show seconds then how it possible? i tried this solution but it show only hour and minute

Answer (score 9):

this function can helps to convert only time, Without date

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String formatedTime(TimeOfDay selectedTime) {
DateTime tempDate = DateFormat.Hms().parse(selectedTime.hour.toString() +
  ":" +
  selectedTime.minute.toString() +
  ":" +
  '0' +
  ":" +
  '0');
var dateFormat = DateFormat("h:mm a");
return (dateFormat.format(tempDate));
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works for both AM and PM times. Rest answers don't work for PM times. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution a little simpler to understand I guess. And there is no need to add any library.

```
String getFormattedDateTime({d = "2022-11-15 14:21:37.152"}){
       List<String> months = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
      ];

      List<String> days = [
        'Monday',
        'Tuseday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday',
        'Sunday',
      ];

      final dateTimeObj = DateTime.parse(d);

      // date format
      String fdate = "${days[dateTimeObj.weekday - 1].substring(0, 3)}, ${months[dateTimeObj.month-1].substring(0, 3)}-${dateTimeObj.day}";
      // time format
      String time = "${(dateTimeObj.hour > 12 ? dateTimeObj.hour - 12 : dateTimeObj.hour).abs()}:${dateTimeObj.minute} ${dateTimeObj.hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM"}";
      return "$fdate $time";
    }
```

This function will return formatted String something like this **Tus, Nov-15 4:54 PM** again you can format it accordingly.