# How to format time from time picker in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter. In my app I have a button which onPressed shows a timepicker. I want to set the title of the button to the time selected by user in this format: 2:30 PM. To do that I need to format the time. I'm using the intl package but can't seem to figure out how to use it to format the time. Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class ShowTimePickerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowTimePickerWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ShowTimePickerWidget> createState() => _ShowTimePickerWidgetState();
}

class _ShowTimePickerWidgetState extends State<ShowTimePickerWidget> {
  TimeOfDay? selectedTime;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        const Icon(Icons.access_time),
        Expanded(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              TimeOfDay time = TimeOfDay.now();
              final pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
                context: context,
                initialTime: time,
              );
              setState(() {
                selectedTime = pickedTime;
              });
            },
            child: Text(
              (selectedTime == null)
                  ? 'Time to start your day'
                  : //set the formatted time string here,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

intl version: 0.18.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67395639/14120486) is what you need, if not, please let me know and I will provide more support.

Happy coding!

Comment: Worked perfectly! But do we have to convert the selected time to string like this: '${pickedTime.hour}:${pickedTime.minute}' or is there another better way to do it?

Comment: String interpolation is the correct way imo, I always use them to join strings without worrying about converting them!

Comment: Why downvoting my answer if it's working and accepted ?

Answer (score 1):

```
final TimeOfDay? timePicked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );
    if (timePicked != null)
      setState(() {
        _selectedTime = timePicked;
      });
    // Conversion logic starts here
    DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("hh:mm").parse(
        _selectedTime!.hour.toString() +
            ":" + _selectedTime!.minute.toString());
    var dateFormat = DateFormat("h:mm a"); // you can change the format here
    print(dateFormat.format(tempDate))
```

Comment: It would be better add some explanation on how it works instead of giving only the code